# REQUEST first used in a middleware but cannot be retrieved from a controller

Tags: dependency-injection, scope, request, microservices, nestjs

REQUEST scope indicates a new instance be created for each request, according to Nest JS the request lifecycle is: middleware, pipes, guards, and interceptor. I am creating a service with scope REQUEST in a middle ware which inits a id of the service instance, and wiring this middleware to every endpoint, expecting fetching the exact same service instance in the controller and following service.

But found out that the service instance id is undefined. If I first use the service in a controller, it is fine: the same instance can be fetched from the following service.

Is this because of the context of the request lifecycle?

**The service:**

```
@Injectable({scope: Scope.REQUEST})
export class IdService {
    private _id: string

    get id(): string {
        return this._id;
    }

    set id(value: string) {
        this._id = value;
    }
}
```

**The middleware**

```
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';

@Injectable()
export class AddIdMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

    constructor(private idService: IdService) {}

    use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void): any {
        const pid = uuidv4()
        this.idService.id = pid
        console.log(`generated tranceId in idService is: ${this.idService.idd}`)

        next();
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
export class XXXController {
  constructor( private idService: IdService) {}

  @Get("/test")
  public async getId() {
    console.log(`the id generated in the PER-REQUEST scope is ${this.idService.id} !!!!!!!!`)

  }
}
```

Comment: this is how JS works. The `this` in your `AddIdMiddleware` is not the same `this` used in `XXXController`. I don't know why you're expecting they to be the same. You can attach data into `req` and then retrieve it from your controller.

Comment: Thank you @MicaelLevi for your answer, I am planning share something for the single req from the very beginning which can be logged in the pipes and guards. I am hoping nest js can provide something out of the box instead of using some packages. By the way, the service I declared with REQUEST scope, from the document, it should be have only one instance for a single request, and be injected to the middleware and the controller. Am I miss something here? From my experiment, if I first use the service in the controller, the following service and repository could fetch the same service instance.

Comment: the thing about nestjs is that they try to reuse things from the nodejs land. I believe you can achieve what you want with https://github.com/Papooch/nestjs-cls. Also, yeah, you're right about the instance. I read your code too quickly. I'm not familiar with other scopes but looks like another instance is created for the middleware. Add some `console.log` in the service's constructor.